# What does "throw" mean in badminton?

Tags: terminology, badminton

I have often heard the term "throw" used in badminton. What does it mean a player loses a point because of a "throw"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular context, the word "[Throw](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/throw+a+game)", could also be interpreted differently. Here it's meant to describe the mis-behaviour of players in a match (could be in other sports as well), to deliberately lose a game for their benefit.

Most recently, during the Olympics of 2012 held in London, four pairs of women's doubles badminton players, were excluded from the tournament because of "throwing" the game.

References:

- [Eight Olympic badminton players disqualified for 'throwing
  games'](http://www.guardian.co.uk/sport/2012/aug/01/london-2012-badminton-disqualified-olympics)
- [Match fixing - Throwing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Match_fixing)

Answer (score 3):

From http://www.badminton-information.com/badminton-terms.html:

> ***Carry*** : An illegal stroke in which the shuttle is not hit, but caught and held on the racket before being released; also called a "*sling*" or **"*throw*"**.

So if the shuttle is held on the racket before it is being released, it is called "throw".

From http://www.badminton-information.com/rules-of-badminton.html

> ### Faults
>
> The rules of badminton consider the following as ***faults***:
>
> - ...
> - If the shuttle is caught and held on the racket and then slung during the execution of a stroke.
> - ...

So it is considered as a *fault*.

[Another source](http://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/sports-badminton.htm)

Comment: Why did you alter the title of the OP? Is it a bad thing a question can have two answers?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - I just improved the title. And why are you asking me that question (to have two answers)?

Comment: Well, you just altered it in such a manner, that "throw" is exclusively meant for badminton. Perhaps you can change "do" in "does" as well.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - Ahh. Thanks for catching that little mistake! Updated. And the question is for badminton so I did like that. If we have the same question for Cricket we could ask "What does "Throw" mean in Cricket?"

Comment: Unless the question has severe grammar problems, I wouldn't alter it's meaning.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - "They" word doesn't look good in the title. (can't understand whom it refers)

Comment: And I felt his answer is better because in this one only thing I see is just some definition copied from third party site which I am not sure, can be trusted. His answer showed more research and looked like believable.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a language barrier at work here. Jacob Jan Tuinstra's answer is interesting but misleading. The context of the question is how "throwing" can *lose a point*. Slinging or throwing the shuttle is a fault in the [BWF Laws of Badminton](http://www.bwfbadminton.org/file.aspx?id=608602&dl=1), 13.3.7, page 8:

> It shall be a fault: if in play, the shuttle is caught and held on the racket and then slung during the execution of a stroke